# 2 sample unpaired t-test giving 0 in excel

Tags: t-test, excel

I have 400 data points, daily data for past year for population A and population B. When I conducted a t-test in excel, it gave me an absolute value of 0.

However, graphically I can clearly see a difference in distributions between the 2 samples (Image attached). Can someone please explain.

I used the following formula in excel;
**T.TEST(arr1,arr2,2,3)** 2-sample t-test with unequal variance[image]

Comment: The result of the procedure T.TEST is the p-value, not the "absolute value" (I'm assuming that you mean the absolute value of the mean difference between the two groups). In your case, it would make a lot of sense for the p-value to be very very very close to 0.

Comment: That $0$ is presumably a $p$-value which is so close to $0$ that it rounds to $0$.  So the result of your calculation is that the two data sets are significantly different